# LINQ Query returns null when executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 2 tables in my database and I am writing a query to get data from a specific column. However the LINQ query is returning me an empty result set. I have read multiple posts on SO and online and have tried `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`. I have tried checking with `Any` but the data set is still empty. I ran the same query on LINQPad and it does return me the correct result.

```
var connString = from firstTable in _dataContext.Connections
    join secondTable in _dataContext.Companies on
    firstTable.CompanyID equals secondTable .CompanyID
    where secondTable .CompanyName == "Name"
    select firstTable .ConnectionString;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it is empty? It might just not have queried yet. Most LINQ queries make use of the `yield` keyword.

Comment: Are you sure the connection string define somewhat in the config file is the same? Like, are you connecting to the same database? Did you open the connection?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, I am using code first approach from entity framework. I do have the connection string in config file. If i pass it manually, it works as well. But I am just unable to retrieve it from the database.

Comment: @MattRowland Actually LINQ queries never use the `yield` keyword.

Comment: is this SQL server?  have you checked your collation?  and did you make sure that company `"Name"` is really in the DB?  You may have special characters, whitespace and many other things screwing with you.

Comment: @MatthewWhited, Yes it is SQLServer and I did check that DB for any white spaces or special characters. The data is clean and the record does exist.

Comment: I'm sure that something is wrong with your db connection. It's impossible for any LINQ query to ever return null. It could potentially return an empty set, but never return null.

Comment: @NetMage Here is a link to some of the LINQ source code. Many of the LINQ queries use `yield`. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs

Comment: Remove your where clause and check again.  It's possible there is not intersection between the tables or there could still be a collation issue. (it's possible that SQL is checking case and whitespace that you don't expect.)

Comment: `null` can be returned if you use and of the `.XxxOrDefault(...)` methods

Comment: @MattRowland The LINQ source code uses `yield`, but LINQ queries do not. If you want to implement your own version of LINQ, or extensions to LINQ, or a database provider for LINQ, you may need `yield`. But you don't typically use it in queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query is working in LINQPad your query is correct, you have a problem in your environment. You need to compare the pieces between your environment and LINQPad to see where the disconnect is occurring.

For example, what is `_dataContext.Connections.Count()` in both places? Same for `_dataContext.Companies.Count()`. Compare different pieces of the query until you find the source of the difference.

Comment: This helped me and I figured that I had one character of in the database name. ONE CHARACTER